# create numbered files in C

Tags: c, string, file

I need to create files that have the same name, but with a number attached to the end of the filename to indicate that it was the nth file made. So in a for loop, I basically want to do this:

```
char *filename = "file";
strcat(filename, i); // put the number i at the end of the filename
```

Clearly that isn't the way to do it, but any ideas as to how I can accomplish this task?

Thanks,
Hristo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
char filename[256];
int i = 1;

// codes omitted...
sprintf(filename, "file%4d", i);
```

Comment: Better use `%04d` unless you like whitespaces in file names

Comment: @mouviciel yes, that was what I wanted to type, my fingers didn't listen to me.  :P

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf()` or `snprintf()` with `"file%d"`.

Comment: I would've been first if it weren't for SO's short answer limit (and the captcha if you edit too fast). Grrr! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprintf.